# Add to html on to class with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'd like to add html on to every element with a certain class but the way I call it:

```
    $(".foldUpSection").find(".header").html($(".foldUpSection").find(".header").html() + 'Some HTML');
```

inserts the code from the first .header.

I tried `this` but after thinking about it I realize it is obviously undefined. Is there a way to reference the current instance of the change in a class wide modification?

Something like:

```
$(".foldUpSection").find(".header").html($("self").html() + 'Some HTML');
```

Comment: [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You work can be more simpler using [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) jquery function

```
$( ".foldUpSection .header" ).append('<div class="miniArrow" style="font-weight:bold;float: right;display:block;width:21px; height:21px; margin-right:15px"><img style="height:13px" src="images/rightArrow.png" /></div>');
```

[Js Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/VWV46/)